# Bootstrap Time picker color of arrow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap time picker in that I wanted to change the arrow colors only on mouse over ...I have used some styles but it's applied on whole block... Any ideas?

```html
 <div uib-timepicker ng-model="item.StartDateTime" 
      ng-change="vm.valueShiftChange(item)" 
      onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'"
      hour-step="1" minute-step="1" show-meridian="true"></div>
```

This is changes only the hr within the box but not changing the arrow color....

Comment: Please also post the CSS that you have tried.

Comment: @Kiran Dash I tried this : onMouseOver="this.style.color='none'"

Answer (score 0):

I have added a below style and its working fine

span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-up:hover:before, span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down:hover:before {
        color: #CCC !important;
    }